# No elimina elementos de mi matriz

Tags: java, android, android-studio

resulta que estaba haciendo una especie de candy crush ( bejeweled ) y a la hora de eliminar los elementos, que forman un match >= a 3, no los elimina. Por ahora hice la comrpobacion de que si hay coincidencias en la parte derecha del elemento (gema) que fue clickeado. Pero no sabria porque hay elementos que los elimina y otros que no.

```
 public void recorrerHorizontalesDerecha (int x, int y){
    GridLayout grid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    boolean ok = false;
    int ub;
    for( int posY = y ; posY < matriz.length ; posY ++){
        if( ( matriz[x][posY] == matriz[x][y + 1] ) && ( matriz[x][posY] == matriz[x][y + 2] )){

            ok = true;
        }
        if ((matriz[x][posY] == matriz[x][y]) && (ok = true)) {

            ub = x * 8 + posY;
            grid.getChildAt(ub).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }else{
            if(matriz[x][posY] != matriz[x][y]) {
                posY = 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Atacaría por una solución recursiva. Tendría primero un listado de coordenadas que son las que se van a eliminar al terminar de procesar y dos numero enteros indicando el tamaño de la pantalla y los limites.

```
List toDeleteCoordinates;
int sizeX;
int sizeY;

public void iniciarRecorrer(int x, int y)
{
   toDeleteCoordinates = new ArrayList<String>();
   checkCoordinates(x, y, matriz[x][y]);

   if(coord.toDeleteCoordinates.size()>=3)
   {
      for(String coord:toDeleteCoordinates)
      {
         //Originalmente era "ub = x * 8 + posY;" pero no tengo muy claro que es, así que lo mantengo
         int ub = coord.split('/')[0] * 8 + coord.split('/')[1];
         grid.getChildAt(ub).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
   }
}

public void recorrer(int x, int y, int valor)
{
   //Revisamos si es el mismo valor
   //Si no es del mismo valor, salimos
   if(matriz[x][y] == valor)
   {
     toDeleteCoordinates.add(x+"/"+y);


     // Revisamos arriba
     if(y-1>=0) //Evitamos salirnos del limite
     {
       recorrer(x,y-1,valor);
     }

     //Revisamos abajo
     if(y+1<=sizeY) //Evitamos salirnos del limite
     {
       recorrer(x,y+1,valor);
     }

     //Revisamos izquierda
     if(x-1<=0) //Evitamos salirnos del limite
     {
       recorrer(x-1,y,valor);
     }

     //Revisamos derecha
     if(x+1<=sizeX) //Evitamos salirnos del limite
     {
       recorrer(x+1,y,valor);
     }
  }
}
```

De esta forma atacarías a todas las direcciones. No he tenido oportunidad de verificar que el código funcione, pero creo que queda claro que es lo que quiero decir.